# jQuery fileupload with hidden files

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, hidden-files

I load pictures using jQuery fileupload with follow params:

```
this.$('input[type=file]').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    url: this.data.url || '/files/upload',
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    previewMaxWidth: 512,
    previewMaxHeight: 512,
    previewCrop: true
});
```

Pay attention to line `acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,`. This line allows only pictures, BUT there is one problem. It's working with hidden files (e.g: file with name **.jpg**) How to restrict such files?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean. I don't understand why `jpg` is an issue, given that it's a valid image file type?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, I mean follow. You have **name.jpg** or **1.jpg** or **.jpg**. Last example doesn't have a name. It only has an extension. I want to restrict such files

Comment: @Mike_Device _"Last example doesn't have a name. It only has an extension. "_ Is requirement to _not_ accept files ending with extension `.jpg` ? Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to where `input type="file"` allows selection of files beginning with `.` ?